# PHPStorm - SCSS file Watcher

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm

I just have a big problem beginning with scss stuff. I have already install scss and add it to phpstorm as a "file watcher".
Until there I was in a peacefull world but I tried to add a partials (file begining with a "_" which are included in the main file style.scss).

I want when I change the scss/style.scss OR partials/_variables.scss that the css/style.css updated.

So my problem is : When I change and save the style.scss file is ok, but when I change the _variables.scss, the style.css still the same.

**Is there any way to WATCH the _variables.scss and generate automatically the main file if it's changed ?**

I've already played with the scope of file watchers, but no way to do it ...

```
css/
    style.css
partials/
    _variables.scss
scss/
    style.scss
```

Comment: I use the LESS pre-processor in PHPStorm and include just my main file with all the @import's. THe FileWatcher also detects changes on other files in the same directory as the main file.

Comment: Ok but the css of the partials scss file are also generated, aren't they ?

Comment: That depends on the parameters you are passing to the SCSS parser in the FileWatcher dialog.

Comment: Juste the basic stuff : --no-cache --update $FileName$:../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
(I know I shouldn't do that with "../" and use ProjectDirectory)
Do you know a parameter to put a condition on which file we give on $FileName$ ?

Comment: Ok your answer made me think and I find a solution, Thanks.
I've just had to regenrate only the style.scss file each time a file was changed.
--no-cache --update $ProjectFileDir$/scss/style.scss:$ProjectFileDir$/css/style.css
I'm not sure it's the perfect answer but it works

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @feeela,

I have my answer :

Change listen all the changing scss, and generate the style.scss each time via

```
--no-cache --update $ProjectFileDir$/scss/style.scss:$ProjectFileDir$/css/style.css
```

So the partials are listened but only the style.css is generated. :)

Comment: I'd suggest using --no-cache --update $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css but make sure to tick 'track only root files' checkbox - should do the thing: watcher will listen to changes in all files, including partials, but only 'main' file (the one that imports other stuff) will be created

Comment: Thanks for your answer lena but that was the problem, the other files like _varaibles.scss were not watched. When I changed them, the style.css wasn't created because PHPStorm didn't notice any changes in style.scss. I'll have a problem if I want add another "root file", but for the moment it's ok.